# Adding images in textview using base adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

I'm working on chat activity where user enter the text to chat. Now I have to implement appending images in the chat activity. I have made custom base adapter to include the message in the list. Now not getting any idea about how to append photos from gallery and camera in this one, like whatsapp. Please help me on this. My code is

PSAdapter.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;



@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
public class PSAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Message> mMessages;



    public PSAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> messages) {
        super();
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mMessages = messages;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mMessages.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {       
        return mMessages.get(position);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Message message = (Message) this.getItem(position);

        ViewHolder holder; 
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.sms, parent, false);
            holder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.message.setText(message.getMessage());

        LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) holder.message.getLayoutParams();

        if(message.isStatusMessage())
        {
            holder.message.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
            lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            holder.message.setTextColor(R.color.textFieldColor);
        }
        else
        {       

            if(message.isMine())
            {
                holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_green);
                lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            }

            else
            {
                holder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_orange);
                lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            }
            holder.message.setLayoutParams(lp);
            holder.message.setTextColor(R.color.textColor); 
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView message;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: use a compound textview

Comment: Ok. Could you please suggest any tutorial for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(in, 0);
            }            
        });
```

By this you can select files from gallery dude. It just intent you to gallery and to choose image.
Acept answer if you got wat you need . Inform me for any issues.

Comment: I know it. But how to display that image in chat box, since it contains only list textview.

Comment: Then in list row place one imageview and make it as invisible probably gone is better, then only it wont show any spaces there. After thet If you select image then place that and put visible from javacode.